# Data structure to be used for streaming data

Tags: data-structures, time

What data structure should you use such that any point in time your server is able to tell you the number of requests processed in the last hour?

For example, at 10:20:23 you ask how many requests were processed; it must tell you the total from 9:20:23 until now. Similarly, at 10:00 it must tell you the total from 9:00.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store all of the data in a standard dynamic array sorted by time.  Whenever there's an incoming request, you append it to the end of the array.

To look up how many requests have occurred in the past hour, you can do a binary search over the array to find the first request that occurred in the hour.  Comparing the index of this array element to the total number of elements will give you the total number of requests in that time window.

To prevent the array from getting too large, one option is to treat the array as a growing ring buffer.  Whenever you run out of space in the array, do a binary search for the first element in the array that occurred within the past hour.  All of the elements before that can be discarded.  If you store the array as a ring buffer, you can effectively in O(1) time delete all those elements by just adjusting the start position to logically remove them from the buffer.  If you still need more space, then you can double the size of the ring buffer and copy the old elements over.  If you enforce a policy of always copying everything over if more than some constant fraction of the buffer is filled after dropping the old elements (say, 75%), then this comes out to requiring amortized O(1) time per insert.

In short, you get amortized O(1) insertion and O(log n) worst-case lookups of how many requests were in the past hour.

Hope this helps!